# jquery IE support for show()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

All,

I have the following code ,

```
    <div id="show" display="none"></div>

    var ele=document.getElementById('show');
    ele.style.display='block';
    ele.style.padding='1px';
    ele.style.borderLeft='solid 1px #d0d0d0';
    ele.style.borderBottom='solid 1px #a0a0a0';
    ele.style.position='absolute';
    ele.style.borderTop='solid 1px #d0d0d0';
    ele.style.borderRight='solid 1px #a0a0a0';
    ele.style.backgroundColor='#ffffaa';
    ele.style.fontSize='12px';
    ele.style.fontFamily='helvetica';
    ele.style.color='black';

    $(window).mouseover(function(event) {
     $("#show").css({'top': (event.pageY)/2, 'left': '10px'});
    });
```

In internet explorer the div does not get displayed could someone please tell me the code change to make it work on IE.

Thanks...................

Comment: why do you set the initial style with JavaScript and not just plain css?

Comment: Need more context. `display="none"` is not valid HTML. Why are you setting all those styles with JavaScript? What are your calculations in that jQuery code supposed to do? Why are you expecting a div with no content to be visible at all?

Comment: this code is called in some function and therefore this is so done.

Comment: Sorry the style is as style='display:none;'

Answer (score 1):

You haven't called show...

```
$("#show").show();
```

Comment: So how did you try to call show.  I can't see it in your example above. I can't guess what you want as a final outcome

Comment: After setting ele.style.display='none'; in the javascript is $("#show").show();  required..

Comment: yes, also display="none" is not valid html.  you should have something like style="display:none" or follow one of the example answers on how to move the styles into a class

Answer (score 0):

First of all you can set all these styles in a css class.

```
#show { copy all your styles here }
```

I think if you want o move the div according to the mouse movement then you have to handle mosemove rather than mouseover. Enclose your mousemove function inside document ready event.

```
$(function(){
    $(window).mousemove(function(event) {
        $("#show").css({'top': (event.pageY)/2, 'left': '10px'});
    });
});
```

***Edit***

If you want the div to act as a tooltip then you can write something like this

```
$("#show").css({'top': event.pageY + 15, 'left': event.pageX + 15});
```

Check the display style of the div to be  block before changing the CSS values.

Comment: Hi ,actually i am trying to generate a div which looks like tooltip

Answer (score 0):

I think you should take out the following line:

```
ele.style.display='block';
```

And then call your jQuery like this:

```
$("#show").css({'top': 100, 'left': 10}).show();// element gets passed to callback function
```

You may notice that I gave `top` a fixed value, just so that you can determine that the element gets displayed AT ALL. If it does, then you can safely say that IE does not get the value of `event.pageY`. Also, pixel-value css properties are defined like above, if I am correct.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, move CSS to a class

```
#show {
// put it here
}
```

Why use javascript when you can do it with CSS? May be IE problem is with that part of JavaScript code.

And your  is empty, hell, but how do you want to see an empty div???? Put some text and try again.

Answer (score 0):

```
          <script type="text/javascript">
                myFlashObject=new Object
                myFlashObject.movie="new_wheel.swf"
                myFlashObject.quality="high"
                myFlashObject.wmode="transparent"
                myFlashObject.width="960px"
                myFlashObject.height="600px"
                myFlashObject.version="6,0,0,0"
                commitFlashObject(myFlashObject, "flash")
          </script>
```

Comment: thanks for posting your answer, it would be nice if you could also add some explanation to your code